# Server is in running status but when tried to hit api it is giving Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

**I'm trying to separate app and server.** It is running properly but when tried to hit "*app.get('/')*" api it is giving *Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000* in Postman even after changing required settings.

**In ./routes/users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { registerUser, getUserList, login, updateUser, deleteUser } = require('../controller/users');
const validateToken = require('../middlewares/auth');

router.post('/login', login);
router.post('/registeruser', registerUser);
router.get('/list', validateToken, getUserList);
router.patch('/update/:userId', validateToken, updateUser);
router.delete('/delete', validateToken, deleteUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**In connect.js (connectDB`your text`)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const color = require('colorette');

const connectDB = (url) => {
    try {
        return mongoose.connect(url, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(color.bgRed(error));
    }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

**In server.js**

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const connectDB = require("./database/connect");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const color = require('colorette');

// ️ handle uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(color.red(`Uncaught Exception Error Occurred ${err}`));
});

const startDB = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        console.log(color.blue(`DB server is connected`));
        server.listen(() => {
            console.log(color.blue(`Node server is running on port ${port}...`));
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(color.red(`ERROR is ${error}`));
    }
};

startDB();
```

**In app.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
const users = require("./routes/users");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(`Hello World`);
})
app.use('a/user', users);
module.exports = app
```

**On Terminal**

```
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
DB server is connected
Node server is running on port 3000...
```

**In Postman**

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
Proxy
id: "958df20d-86ee-40af-8d08-4c3274d302ca"
disabled: false
host: "127.0.0.1"
match: {…}
port: 3000
tunnel: false
authenticate: false
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 515bf6ca-1031-4198-8fda-9c0f99b55c83
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive

Separation of app and server file in Express and Nodejs

Comment: I want to do this "Separation of app and server in Express and Nodejs ?"

Comment: You haven't export anything from `app.js` how you require and using it?

Comment: I have exported it but not written here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't passed the port `3000` into the `listen()` method. Since you already importing Express's `app` instance, use `express`'s `listen()` method instead of using `http.createServer()`. Because express already doing the same.

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const connectDB = require("./database/connect");
const color = require('colorette');

// ️ handle uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(color.red(`Uncaught Exception Error Occurred ${err}`));
});

const startDB = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        console.log(color.blue(`DB server is connected`));
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(color.blue(`Node server is running on port ${port}...`));
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(color.red(`ERROR is ${error}`));
    }
};

startDB();
```

Comment: It's not a problem using `http.createServer(app)`, that's [exactly what Express does itself](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2a00da2067b7017f769c9100205a2a5f267a884b/lib/application.js#L633-L636). The main issue here is not passing a valid port to `listen()`.

Comment: Thank you. I used app.listen() instead of server.createServer () method, Now it is working. Actually I followed this article to implement this https://dev.to/nermineslimane/always-separate-app-and-server-files--1nc7

Comment: @MrigendrakumarP that article passes a port to `listen()`, which you don't do in your code.

Comment: @robertklep. Thanks for pointing it. I updated my answer

Comment: @robertklep There is also 1 issue I encountered that is when I hit app.get('/) it is working but app.use('/a/user') is giving me <pre>Cannot POST /a/user/registeruser</pre>

Comment: You never shared the `./routes/users`. Something wrong there

Comment: @BadPiggie Please check I added in the description

Comment: What exact url you tried?

Comment: I tried to hit this url http://localhost:3000/a/user/registeruser but it is giving me <pre>Cannot POST /a/user/registeruser</pre>